# Correct digits meaning?

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

**I don't understand the meaning of correct digits in this example? please explain**

[image]

Comment: @ Moo okay. Is this something that has been already computed or something I should figure out by looking? I understand your explanation by the way.

Comment: e.g. if I remove the underlines then I ask you how many correct digits for the second iteration, can you find it?

Comment: I see, so it's not by looking.. just wanted to make sure .. thanks :)